# StretchBlt() doesn't create a mirror image

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi, stretchblt

According to MSDN:

> StretchBlt creates a mirror image of a bitmap if the signs of the nWidthSrc and nWidthDest parameters or if the nHeightSrc and nHeightDest parameters differ.

So I tried creating upside-down image. I have a class looking like this:

```
class Picture
{
 private:
 HBITMAP bmp; //Bitmap
 HDC pdc; //Device context
 short int w; //Weidth of bitmap
 short int h; //Heighth of bitmap

 public:
 short int x;
 short int y;
 void draw(HDC);
 void upside_down();
}
```

and I have this method:

```
void Picture::upside_down()
{
 HDC dc = CreateCompatibleDC(pdc);
 HBITMAP bmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(pdc, w, h);
 SelectObject(dc, bmap);
 BitBlt(dc, 0, 0, w, h, pdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
 StretchBlt(pdc, 0, 0, w, h, dc, 0, 0, w, -h, SRCCOPY);
 DeleteDC(dc);
 DeleteObject(bmap);
}
```

but it doesn't work, nothing happens. I wonder if it's something with DC compability, I've always had problems understanding the logic behind that.

So, what should I do so I could get my bitmap flipped?

Comment: The flipping logic looks right. By "*nothing happens*", do you mean no image at all? And no image without the negative height either? Presumably you have something else wrong...

Comment: Well when I tried to change some parameters I got, for example, completely dark image. These parameters I shown with my code seem to be correct, but instead of flipped image I'm getting the same image all the time, unchanged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To flip the picture, you don't negate the height of the source -- you negate the height of the destination. To go with this, you have to specify the *bottom* of your destination rectangle as the origin, so your call would looks something like this:

```
StretchBlt(pdc, 0, h, w, -h, dc, 0, 0, w, h, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: Should this be pdc, 0, h-1, w, -h, dc, ... ?  The first line would be the end which is h-1...?